# ClassLoader doesn't find file at kubernetes

Tags: spring, kubernetes

In my project I use the file from the `resources/key` folder using the ClassLoader and it looks like this

```java
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(folder+"/myfile.json").getFile());
```

folder in application.properties is written like this `key/`

Locally, this approach works correctly and I have no problems with it. Problems arise on kubernetes when the path in which the required file is located is written in the folder field and the error says that the file does not exist at this path. As I understand it, Classloader is looking for a file in target and this creates a problem on kubernetes. how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

```
   InputStream fIs = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(folder+"/myfile.json").toAbsolutePath();
```

With this approach, it turns out to solve the problem and the file can be found if in Intellij Idea in the working directory write the path to the resources folder. How to solve this problem with Classloader is not yet clear.

Comment: Are you running spring boot app inside a pod? You can use ```kubectl exec``` command to check if file exists or not.

Comment: yes, exist, i checked